# How to pass action to another action if no params are present ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 2 actions in my code. One is getting data based on year month and user id.

The other one is updating data based on some other params.

Upon success of second method, I want to run first action so that my component will re-render with the updated contents.

```
export const GetConsultantProjects = (userId, month, year) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: START_LOADING})
        globalAxios().get(`/api/v1/time_registrations`, {
            params: {
                user_id: userId,
                month: month,
                year: year
            }
        }).then(resultSet => {
            if (resultSet) {
                dispatch({type: STOP_LOADING})
                dispatch({type: GET_CONSULTANT_PROJECTS, payload: resultSet.data})
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err.response) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
}

export const UpdateProjectTime = (hour, date, projectId, userId, token, activity, timeId) => {
    let bodyFormData = new FormData();
    if(token && token.length !== 0) {bodyFormData.append('project[project_times_attributes][0][token]', token);}
    if(activity && activity.length !== 0) {bodyFormData.append('project[project_times_attributes][0][activity]', activity);}
    if(timeId && timeId.length !== 0) {bodyFormData.append('project[project_times_attributes][0][id]', timeId);}
    bodyFormData.append('project[project_times_attributes][0][user_id]', userId);
    bodyFormData.append('project[project_times_attributes][0][date]', date);
    bodyFormData.append('project[project_times_attributes][0][project_id]', projectId);
    bodyFormData.append('project[project_times_attributes][0][hours]', hour);
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: START_LOADING})
        globalAxios().put(`/api/v1/time_registrations/${projectId}`, bodyFormData)
            .then(resultSet => {
                if (resultSet) {
                    dispatch(GetConsultantProjects()) // I want to run it again but I have no params here. How to pass them and run it again??
                    dispatch({type: UPDATE_PROJECT_TIME, payload: resultSet.data})
                    dispatch({type: STOP_LOADING})
                }
            }).catch(err => {
            if (err.response) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

`dispatch(GetConsultantProjects())`

I want to run it again but I have no params here. Like month, year and user_id.

How to pass them and run it again??

Comment: Do you use Redux state management in your application? If so your scenario is quite possible to tackle.

Comment: @DushanRandikaYes I am using redux thunk in my application.

Comment: If you are using redux thunk that would be an advantage here. I can arrange a code sample for your question. But there can be some differentiates in state management in my solution. If that's okay i will give you an solution.

Comment: @DushanRandika Sure post the sample and I will try to get the gist from it. The problem is that I am not able to get the params thing from the first action that I want to pass into second one to re-render the component again. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to calling a function and calling another function by looking at the first ones success status, you definitely need a way to handle the success state of the first function. The below sandbox is a sample solution for achieving the thing you have mentioned here. What I am doing is getting a success response from the first function as a prop and fire the second function in componentWillUpdate.

That is the most popular version of calling a function by looking at the other functions behavior in react developers. I hope that would give some help to tackle your problem. if there is something to add or need to change mention it in the comment section.

Sandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/call-function-by-looking-at-another-functions-status-rn7hg

Open the solution in a new window and debug. You will see how the console log are coming and what is the flow of calling functions.